# From EJB 2.0 to EJB 3.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, websphere-7, remoteobject, initial-context

Here Is the code that I have to create an EJB 2.0 
How can I convert this so can be used for EJB 3.0

```
java.lang.Object ejbHomeStub = initCtx.lookup(ejbJNDIName);
EJBHome ejbHome = (EJBHome) 
    javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ejbHomeStub, EJBHome.class);
EJBMetaData ejbMetaData = ejbHome.getEJBMetaData();
Class ejbHomeClass = ejbMetaData.getHomeInterfaceClass();
//get ejb object of home interface type
ejbHome = (EJBHome) javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ejbHome, ejbHomeClass);
//create ejb remote object
Method ejbMethodCreate = ejbHomeClass.getDeclaredMethod(EJB_CREATE, null);
ejbRemoteObj = (EJBObject) ejbMethodCreate.invoke(ejbHome, null);
```

Comment: See http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2006/jw-0814-ejb.html

Comment: I appreciate the reply, I have reviewd that article before but my question is a little bit more speciffic. How can I create the ejbRemoteObj in a **generic** way withotu using the home since it is gone in EJB3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "how do I add EJB 3.0 interfaces to my EJB 2.0 JARs", then you don't need to convert the client or bean since EJB 3.0 is backwards compatible with EJB 2.0.  Instead, just update ejb-jar.xml to remove the XSD, add XSD+xmlns, and update the version attribute of `<ejb-jar/>`.

If you mean "how do I convert this to annotations", then use the `@RemoteHome` annotation on the bean class, and keep your interfaces the same.

If you mean "how do I convert the EJB to use business interface instead of homes", then you can't do that directly, since you have to know the type of the business interface a priori:

```
java.lang.Object businessObjectStub = initCtx.lookup(ejbJNDIName);
BusinessObject businessObject = (BusinessObject)
    javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(businessObjectStub, BusinessObject.class);
```

(Some application servers do not require a narrow for EJB 3.0, but WebSphere Application Server 7.0 does.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I meant the third suggestion that you had. I am calling different beans from a servlet. we used to specify the ejbJNDIName (as it shown in my code. And the code is generic so it could handle any type of bean with a home interface. But EJB3 do not have a home interface. I do not want to create one because it kills all the purpose of having EJB3. I am just trying to figure it out how to do the "generic" call without specifying the BusinessObject

Comment: I would say the greatest benefit of EJB 3 is annotations, not the remove of home interfaces.  In any case, I don't know how to do the equivalent on WebSphere Application Server 7.0.